# join a query multiply the results

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this query and works great. it gives to me some kpis about time, related to an equipment x, and this work selecting the shifts to evaluate. I need to join the information comming from a second query, that works whit the same id of shifts to work, but when i Add the parameters of this query to the first one, the results becomes incremented, for instance, the sum of the firs values gives 24 (24 hrs) but when i relate this query with the second one, te results increments its values and i cant realize whats wrong.

The first query:

```
SELECT *
,(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia+Accidente)*100 as [Disp_Fisica]
,IsNULL((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia),0),0)*100 as [Disp_Mecanica]
,IsNULL((Efectivo+Demora)/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva),0),0)*100 as [Uso_Disponib]
,IsNULL(Efectivo/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora),0),0)*100 as [Efic_Operacional]
FROM (
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Efectivo],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Demora],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Reserva],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Mantencion],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Averia],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Accidente]
                        FROM hist_eqmtlist ,hist_statusevents, hist_exproot
WHERE  hist_eqmtlist.unit     = 'Pala' 
   and hist_exproot.shiftindex between '29976' and '29977'
   and hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex 
   and hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid 
   and  hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_eqmtlist.unit
) A
order by A.eqmt
```

the result given by this query:

```
unit    eqmt    Efectivo    Demora  Reserva Mantencion  Averia  Accidente   Disp_Fisica Disp_Mecanica   Uso_Disponib    Efic_Operacional
Camion  CAM336   16,8      2,6   4,35   0   0   0,2 99,0    100 81,8    86,4
```

the second query gives to me the tons by equipment

```
SELECT hist_exproot.shiftdate , hist_dumps.shiftindex, hist_dumps.truck, sum(hist_dumps.dumptons) AS 'Toneladas'
        FROM Powerview.dbo.hist_dumps hist_dumps, Powerview.dbo.hist_exproot hist_exproot
        WHERE hist_dumps.shiftindex = hist_exproot.shiftindex
        GROUP BY hist_exproot.shiftdate, hist_dumps.truck,  hist_dumps.shiftindex
        ORDER BY shiftdate
```

The result given by this query is the amount of tons by shift by equip

```
shiftdate   shiftindex  truck           Toneladas
2011-01-01  29950       CAM336          8964,00054931641
```

I Need to join both querys but when i do it, it multiply the values, how shoukd i build the relations?

Im trying adding this on the select part, under the sums:

and on where:

```
hist_exproot.shiftindex
```

and the query becomes this:

```
SELECT *
,(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/(Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia+Accidente)*100 as [Disp_Fisica]
,IsNULL((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva)/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva+Mantencion+Averia),0),0)*100 as [Disp_Mecanica]
,IsNULL((Efectivo+Demora)/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora+Reserva),0),0)*100 as [Uso_Disponib]
,IsNULL(Efectivo/NULLIF((Efectivo+Demora),0),0)*100 as [Efic_Operacional]
FROM (
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Efectivo],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Demora],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Reserva],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Mantencion],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Averia],
             sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as [Accidente],
             sum (hist_dumps.dumptons) as [Toneladas]
                        FROM hist_eqmtlist ,hist_statusevents, hist_exproot,hist_dumps
WHERE  hist_eqmtlist.unit     = 'Pala' 
   and hist_exproot.shiftindex between '29976' and '29977'
   and hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex 
   and hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid 
   and  hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex
   and hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_dumps.shiftindex
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_eqmtlist.unit
) A
order by A.unit
```

and when i need to keep the resutls for the tons of and the indicators given by the querys when the arent together, the resutls turns into this when the sum of "efectivo, demora reserva and accidente" shouldn't result more than 24 (24 hrs)

```
unit    eqmt          Efectivo  Demora  Reserva  Accidente  Toneladas
Camion   CAM336         9678    1498    2156        109     2342022
```

Comment: You have pasted your second query as the results of your first query.   Please edit and show the results of your first query.

Comment: i fixed the result of the query!